# stop the setInterval if the content returned is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

So I am retrieving some data via POST using ajax, every 5 seconds, what I am trying to achieve is if the php file ouputs something, then stop the setInterval somehow or set it to 9999999.

Here is what I've tried:

```
var interval = DEFINEDFROMMYQL;
        $(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url/file.php",
                    data: "whatever=2", 
                    success: function(html) {
                        $("#new").html(html);
                        if(html.lenght > 0) {
                            var interval = 99999999999999;
                        }
                   }
                });
            }, interval);
        });
```

I'm a newbie, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: start by checking errors in console... your typo of `lenght` will throw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**clearInterval()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) to stop the timer started by `setInterval` and correct the **typo** `html.lenght`  to `html.length`

```
// var interval = DEFINEDFROMMYQL;
$(function() {
yourInterval = setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "url/file.php",
           data: "whatever=2", 
           success: function(html) {
                    $("#new").html(html);  

                    if(html.length > 0) {
                    ///var interval = 99999999999999;
                      clearInterval(yourInterval);
                    }
             }
         });
   }, interval);
});
```

Comment: He needs the `interval` variable for the timer.

Comment: Also `html.length`, not `.lenght`

Comment: Thank you, the thing was that Chrome didn't thrown any error, anyways your example was great, marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this a couple of different ways, but based on your question ("stop the setinterval somehow") let's switch the implementation to a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and also refactor the code in to a function we can recall. So...

```
var interval = DEFINEDFROMMYQL;
$(function() {

    // establish a function we can recall
    function getDataFromServer(){
        // this encapsulates the original code in a function we can re-call
        // in a setTimeout later on (when applicable)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url/file.php",
            data: "whatever=2", 
            success: function(html) {
                $("#new").html(html);

                // only if the length is 0 do we re-queue the function
                // otherwise (becase it's setTimeout) it will just die
                // off and stop.
                if(html.lenght == 0) {
                    setTimeout(getDataFromServer, interval);
                }
           }
        });
    }
    // make an initial call to the function to get the ball rolling
    setTimeout(getDataFromServer, interval);
    // if you want it to execute immediately instead of wait out the interval,
    // replace the above line to simply:
    //getDataFromServer();
});
```